# Equivalent of \rotOmega in math environments

Tags: symbols

Is there an equivalent of \rotOmega symbol in math environments?

```latex
\documentstyle{article}

\usepackage{phonetic}

\begin{document}

\rotOmega works, but I would like rather to put it in math environments like $\rotOmega$, but it does not work. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\mbox{\rotOmega}$`

Comment: @egreg unfortunately this is too small, and very text shaped, I just want a 180 deg rotation of $\Omega$.

Comment: So you want a *normal* size Omega, but rotated?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use it math environments.

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is a useful resource for these types of questions: it gives `\mho` as pointed out for this question.

Comment: Thanks @DrewBrady, your suggestion is highly useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol you are looking for is defined as `\mho` in `amsfonts`.

`\mho` is natively a math symbol.

(The name is derived from the appearance of the Omega used to represent "ohm".)

Answer (score 2):

`\rotOmega` produces a small glyph. If you want a normal size reversed Omega, you can use `graphicx`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rOmega}{{\mathpalette\rotate@symbol\Omega}}
\newcommand{\rotate@symbol}[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In math mode it is $\rOmega+\Omega$

\end{document}
```

[image]